# How to get SOAPAction from the WSDL using Java

Tags: java, soap

I am using javax.wsdl package for parsing the wsdl file.

I am not sure how to get the SOAPAction of an operation from the wsdl file.

I am able to get the javax.wsdl.Operation object using the WSDLFactory. But I find no way to get the SOAPAction of that operation.

Anybody has idea on how to get it?

Thanks,
Maviswa

Answer (score 10):

You need to get the `ExtensibilityElement` that corresponds to the `SOAPOperation` and extract the `SOAPAction` from there.

Let's take a simple WSDL as example, from the [TempConvert Web Service](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx), and extract the SOAP action from its `CelsiusToFahrenheit` operation; I'm going after this part:

```
<wsdl:binding name="TempConvertSoap" type="tns:TempConvertSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
```

The following code prints the value of the SOAP action for the `CelsiusToFahrenheit` operation:

```
WSDLFactory factory = WSDLFactory.newInstance();
WSDLReader reader = factory.newWSDLReader();
Definition definition = reader.readWSDL("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl");
Binding binding = definition.getBinding(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "TempConvertSoap"));
BindingOperation operation = binding.getBindingOperation("CelsiusToFahrenheit", null, null); 
List extensions = operation.getExtensibilityElements();
if (extensions != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < extensions.size(); i++) {
        ExtensibilityElement extElement = (ExtensibilityElement) extensions.get(i); 

        // ....

        if (extElement instanceof SOAPOperation) {
            SOAPOperation soapOp = (SOAPOperation) extElement;
            System.out.println(soapOp.getSoapActionURI());
        }

        // ....
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit
```